# Should I write a Test that already passes?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I'm talking about uncle bob's rules of TDD:

1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make a failing unit test pass.
2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures are failures.
3. You are not allowed to write any more production code than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.

My problem is that what happens when you expect to create a feature that can generate more than 1 result, and at first iteration you implement codes that can satisfy every scenario?
I wrote such a code once, because that was the only solution which hit my mind first.

I'd say I didn't violate any of these 3 rules.

1. I wrote a test with least possible conditions to fail.
2. Then I implemented the feature with sufficient codes to pass the test (and that was the only solution I came up with; so I'd say least possible codes I could have wrote).
3. And then I wrote the next test to discover that It was already passing.

Now what about the rules ?
Am I not allowed to write this test even if the feature is a **soooper** important one ? Or should I rollback and start over ?

I'd also mention that this method cannot be refactored according to the result or data fed to it. Right now the example situation I can think about is a little stupid but bear with me please. take a look at this for example:
I want to create a method to add numbers, this is pretty much all I can do. White a failing test:

```
public function it_can_add_numbers()
{
    $this->add(2, 3)->shouldReturn(5);
}
```

Then make it pass:

```
public function add($numberOne, $numberTwo)
{
    return $numberOne + $numberTwo;
}
```

Now one could argue that I should have returned 5 in first iteration because that was enough to pass the test and to introduce regression as well, but this is not an actual problem, so please bear with me and suppose this is the only solution one could think of.
Now my company want me to make sure that they are able to add 12 and 13 because these are some internal magical numbers that we'd be using quite a lot of time. I go ahead and write another test, because this is how I'm supposed to verify a feature.

```
public function it_can_add_twelve_and_thirteen()
{
    $this->add(12, 13)->shouldReturn(25);
}
```

turns out the test is already passing.
At this point, I can choose to not write the test, but what if at a later time someone make changes in actual codes and make it

```
public function add($numberOne, $numberTwo)
{
    return 5;
}
```

The test will still pass but the feature is not there.

So what about those situations when you cannot immediately think about a possible flaw to introduce in first iterations before making improvements ? should I leave it here and wait for someone to come over and screw it up ? should I leave this case for regression tests ?

Comment: The mistake here is assuming that you should rigidly and blindly follow those three rules at all times ;)  The real rule is "write a test when you perceive it to have value".

Comment: I've saw more than once projects failing miserably just because some manger blindly adopted tdd. So many times unit tests and test coverage are badly used just to cover the real problems that nobody would like to address

Comment: @OliCharlesworth thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to hear, and I personally believe in same but still I see a lot of people advocating the rules. Some believe that following them rigidly will eventually shape the codebase much better.

Comment: @Gufran: Agreed.  That's not to say that the concepts behind TDD aren't useful or interesting, it's just that they're not a silver-bullet solution..

Answer (score 3):

To be true to the rule number 3 in uncle bob's rules, after writing the test:

```
public function it_can_add_numbers()
{
    $this->add(2, 3)->shouldReturn(5);
}
```

The *correct* code would be:

```
public function add($numberOne, $numberTwo)
{
    return 5;
}
```

Now, when you add the second test, it *will* fail, which will make you change the code to comply with both tests, and then refactor it to be DRY, resulting in:

```
public function add($numberOne, $numberTwo)
{
    return $numberOne + $numberTwo;
}
```

I won't say that it is the "only true way" to code, and @Oli and @Leo have a point that you should not stop thinking like a programmer because you are TDDing, but the above process is an example of following the 3 rules you stated in TDD...

Comment: I mentioned about the situation in my question. I know that the correct solution in first iteration would be to return 5, but what if you cannot think about it the first time ? what if it never hit your mind and you never care about it because it was never the correct answer at first ? and because it was never the correct answer you'd never ever think about the same in future.

Comment: Pure TDDers force themselves to think like that. You can ask the same thing about a fully-featured method (mainly because you designed it in your head before starting to write the tests). If you wrote something which is _not_ the minimum needed to pass the test - this is not pure TDD.

Comment: makes sense. so this is something that belongs to purists? Or maybe a code smell (or test smell!) sort of something? because if a test passess without going through the iteration it is worthless (it violates rule #2), and if a super important test is seemingly worthless then should I stop and think about possible flaws before moving on ?

Answer (score 3):

If you write a passing test, you are not doing TDD.

That is not to say that the test has no value, but it says very clearly that your new test is not "driving design" (or "driving development", the "other" DD).  You may need the new test for regression or to satisfy management or to bring up some code coverage metric, but you don't need it to drive your design or your development.

You did violate Uncle Bob's third rule, insofar as you wrote more logic than was required to pass the test you had.

It's OK to break the rules; it's just not OK to break the rules and say you're not breaking them.  If you want to rigidly adhere to TDD as Uncle Bob defines it, you need to follow his rules.

Answer (score 0):

If the feature is really simple, like the addition example,  I would not worry about implementing it with just one test.  In more complex, real-world situations, implementing the entire solution at once may leave you with poorly structured code because you don't get the chance to evolve the design and refactor the code.  TDD is a design technique that helps you write better code and requires you to be constantly THINKING, not just following rules by rote.

Answer (score 0):

TDD is a best practice, not a religion. if your case is trivial/obvious, just write the right code instead of doing some artificial useless refactoring